# Does not Execute the if statement in cellForRowAtIndexPath in static TableView Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hi guys so i have been stuck with a problem that i have been using static tableView. And i have put an dynamic tableView to show Comments. but the problem is that if i not put an if statement in cellForRowAtIndexPath the view shows nothing.. and when i use the if statement the code does not go through the if block and i have also tried it in other projects and using if statements is the only way..

so the code for ShotDetailTableViewController is this

```
import UIKit
import FLAnimatedImage

class ShotDetailTableViewController: UITableViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var bgImageView: FLAnimatedImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var viewsCount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var likesCount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var commentsCount: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var avatarImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var reboundCount: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var attachmentCount: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var tagsCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var reboundCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var attachmentCollectionView: UICollectionView!

    @IBOutlet weak var commentTableView: UITableView!

    var shots : [Shot] = [Shot]()
    var comments : [Comment] = [Comment]()
    var shot : Shot!

    var reboundPages = 1
    var attachmentPages = 1

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        title = shot.title

        bgImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: shot.imageUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "1"))

        viewsCount.text = "\(shot.viewsCount)"
        likesCount.text = "\(shot.likesCount)"
        commentsCount.text = "\(shot.commentCount)"

        avatarImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: shot.user.avatarUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "2"))
        usernameLabel.text = "\(shot.user.username)"
        descriptionLabel.text = "\(shot.description)"

        reboundCount.text = "\(shot.reboundCount)"
        attachmentCount.text = "\(shot.attachmentsCount)"

        let api = DribbleObjectHandler()
       api.loadComments(shot.commentsUrl, completion:didLoadComments)
     }

    func didLoadComments(comments : [Comment]){
      self.comments = comments
      self.commentTableView.reloadData()
    }

  // MARK: - Table view data source

  override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    if tableView == commentTableView {
      return 1
    } else {
      return 1
     }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        if tableView == commentTableView {
          return comments.count
        } else {
        return super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView == commentTableView {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CommentCell

        // Configure the cell...
        let comment = comments[indexPath.row]

        cell.nameLabel.text = comment.user.name
        cell.commentLabel.text = comment.body

        cell.avatarImageView.sd_setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: comment.user.avatarUrl), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "2"))

      return cell

        } else {
          let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
          return cell
      }
  }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Please Bear in mind i am fairly new to Swift

Thanks in Advance
Aryan

Answer (score 0):

Set the delegate for the commentTableView in view did load.

```
commentTableView.delegate = self
```

or wire it up in the storyboard (ctrl-drag to yellow icon in view controller, select delegate and datasource)

Answer (score 0):

When you use a Static TVC, none of the normal delegates of your TVC will be called, which include `numberOfSectionsInTableView`, `numberOfRowsInSection`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You should delete them from your class and migrate any code that needs to be executed to a different function, and `viewDidLoad` is a good spot, like @Shane mentioned.